# JavaScript – copyNode of TextArea

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, clonenode

I found interesting bug in google chrome version 43.0.2357.65. (In older versions or other browsers, I cannot reproduce this bug).

I have that code (textArea is HTMLTextAreaElement, textArea.parentNode is HTMLSpanElement):

```
alert('alert 0 = ' + textArea.scrollHeight);
var copyArea = textArea.cloneNode(false);
textArea.parentNode.appendChild(copyArea);
alert('alert 1 = ' + copyArea.scrollHeight);
copyArea.value = textArea.value;
alert('alert 2 = ' + copyArea.scrollHeight);
textArea.parentNode.removeChild(copyArea);
```

There are results:

```
IE9: alert 0 = 100; alert 1 = 10; alert 2 = 100
Chrome 36.0.1985.125: alert 0 = 100; alert 1 = 10; alert 2 = 100
Chrome 43.0.2357.65: alert 0 = 100; alert 1 = 10; alert 2 = 10
```

Why I get this alert 2 = 10? Where can be problem?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, there is cloneNode

Comment: Please create a JSFiddle or provide your html as well.

Comment: With Google Chrome update 43.0.2357.81 all works fine.